# How to pass more than one argument to Process?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I would like to start a function with multiple arguments as a new Process using the multiprocess module:

```
 def f(*args):
    x= args[0]
    y= args[1]
    return x+y

p = Process(target=f,args=??)
```

I would like to know how I can pass the multiple arguments; the documentation as far as I know doesn't mention that.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It doesn't seem like much of a stretch to imagine how you would pass multiple arguments from the code you have posted

Comment: Are you looking for multiprocessing.starmap()?

Comment: shouldn't `args*` actually be `*args`?

Comment: I have tried to provide the arguments as a tuple and a list respectively, but I didn't know how to catch them in the function

Answer (score 0):

Using separate arguments:

```py
def f(x,y):
    return x+y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f,args=(1,2,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Using `*args` syntax:

```py
def f(*args):
    x = args[0]
    y = args[1]
    return x+y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f,args=(1,2,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```